# La connotation de l’expression « lever le coude »

Tags: expressions, connotation

Quand on « lève le coude », je me demande si au-delà de boire simplement jusqu'à être saoul, on s'y adonne toujours plus que de raison ? Si c’est le cas, cette expression prend-elle une connotation négative, renvoyant à la boisson excessive et imprudente lors d'une soirée bien arrosée ?

> On **lève le coude** quand on est heureux.

À titre d’exemple, dans la phrase ci-dessus, se pourrait-il que « lever le coude » signifie consommer avec modération, en fonction du contexte ? Ou bien on finit forcément par abuser, au point d'avoir la gueule de bois terrible le lendemain ?

Answer (score 3):

Je me souviens avoir appris cette expression autour de ma dix-huitième année ; j'avais ramené ma première copine à la maison, et lors de l'apéritif, mon père et ses amis, de vieux sages, l'avaient gratifié d'un "Elle lève bien le coude la petite !". S'ensuivit :

> Papa, ça veut dire quoi lever le coude ?
>
> Ça veut dire que ton coude n'est pas souvent sur la table, mais plutôt occupé à rapprocher ton verre de ta bouche...

Blague à part, et à mon humble avis, il n'y a pas de jugement de valeur dans l'expression. Cela n'est en soit qu'un constat, comme mon père me l'avait fait remarquer ; on boit beaucoup, mais sans notion de limite (pas assez ou trop, ou juste ce qu'il faut). On boit beaucoup, c'est tout !

Answer (score 1):

*Le Petit Robert* nous dit :

> *Lever le coude :* boire beaucoup.

Le *TLFi*, de son côté, nous indique aussi :

> *Au fig., fam. Lever, hausser le coude.* Boire beaucoup, être enclin à boire.

Il faut ici comprendre *BOIRE* en ce sens, commun et défini dans tous les dictionnaires :

> *Le Petit Robert, 1.2* : **ABSOLT et SPÉCIALT** Prendre des boissons alcoolisées avec excès.
>
> [*TLFi, 2b*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boire) : *Spéc.* Boire du vin ou des boissons alcoolisées. *En partic.* avoir coutume d'en boire avec excès, être alcoolique.

Si le TLFi cautionne un usage moins lourd *(simplement boire, pas forcément avec excès)*, on devinera néanmoins qu’il est fait référence à la seconde acception mentionnée lorsque, comme c’est le cas, on y adjoint l’adverbe *beaucoup*, comme le font les deux définitions de *hausser le coude*.

Conclusion : il semble que l’excès fasse partie des nuances sous-entendues par la levée du coude.

---

<sub>En tant que francophone de naissance et de culture, cette expression me semblait comporter une notion de boire autours d’une table en bonne compagnie, sans préjugé de limites, mais sans non plus de préjugé d’excès. Une expression plaisante pour décrire un bon moment entre amis ou en famille, où l’alcool est présent, mais ne coule pas forcément à grands flots. Peut-être n’est-ce que moi ? Du moins, les dictionnaires ne semblent pas cautionner cette interprétation...</sub>